# Razor - Enviar parâmetros para um modal Bootstrap

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, razor, parâmetros, modal

Eu tenho uma lista (grid) e quero abrir um modal bootstrap com detalhes da linha escolhida.
Para construir a lista eu estou a usar - `@foreach`, e armazeno os dados numa `viewbag`.

A ideia é abrir a janela modal e usar os dados da `viewbag`.

```
@foreach (var _img in ViewBag.Images)
{
    <a href="#modal60" data-toggle="modal">
        <img src="~/Content/images/products/@_img.MediaFileName"  />
    </a>
    ViewBag.ImageFile = _img.MediaFileName;
    ViewBag.ImageId = _img.ProductsMediasId;
}
```

O problema é que `ViewBag.ImageFile` não fica com o valor correto da imagem selecionada.

Comment: Você já possui o `modal`? Poste o restante de seu código juntamente com o método para **detalhes**.

Comment: Olá, jeralmente não fazemos dessa forma, pois não há necessidade de salvar os detalhes de todos os itens na mesma página. Uma abordagem mais interesante seria quando você clicar no item para ver os detalhes a pagina fazser uma requisição para o servidor e retornar apenas o detalher do item em questão.

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar o data-transfer da biblioteca js do bootstrap. no caso estou pegando o parâmetro de um eval mas você pode pegar o parâmetro de onde quiser:

```
<a><i class="fa fa-times" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalexcluir" data-transfer1="<%#Eval("nome") %>"></i></a>
```

e no javascript basta usar:

```
    $('#modalexclui').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
            var nome = button.data('transfer1')
            var modal = $(this)
            modal.find('#textoexclui').text(nome )
```

Comment: muuuito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O `viewbag` serve para passar dados do `controller` para a `view`, não para ser usado na `view` dessa forma. Use variáveis.

No caso específico do seu código, cada iteração do laço sobrescreve `ViewBag.ImageFile` e `ViewBag.ImageId`, que ficarão com o valor do último item de `ViewBag.Images`.

Comment: Sim, é isso que ocorre, a ViewBag fica com o último valor apenas. Confesso que não consigo imaginar como passar para o modal a chave do item selecionado.

Comment: Você precisa enviar os dados para a action que gera a modal, se ela é gerada por um controller. Se você gera ou quer gerar o HTML dela na mesma view que mostrou, use os valores no HTML. A viewbag serve para passar dados do controller para a view, setar o seu valor na view é usar errado.

Answer (score 0):

O `ViewBag` coloca as informações dentro do HTML, servindo para transportar dados da `Controller` para `View`. No seu caso, supondo o modal assim:

```
<div id="modal60">
    <div class="modal-header">
       <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
       <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <input type="text" name="imagemId" id="imagemId" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Na `view`, adicione um `data-id` com a informação que você quer passar para o modal bootstrap:

```
@foreach (var _img in ViewBag.Images)
{
    <a href="#modal60" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@_img.ProductsMediasId" class="abrirModal">
        <img src="~/Content/images/products/@_img.MediaFileName"  />
    </a>
}
```

E trate esse `ID` via jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".abrirModal", function () {
    var idImagem = $(this).data("id");
    $(".modal-body #imagemId").val(idImagem);
    //exibir modal
});
```

Comment: Muuuuito obrigado!

Comment: Se essa resposta solucionou o problema, marque como a Solução para ajudar quem tiver o mesmo problema futuramente :)

Comment: Olá, infelizmente não deu certo...

Comment: Qual o erro? Você deve ter feito algo errado... :)